# Ask your team for your master key and put it in ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"] on heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to deploy my application in heroku, but I can not do anything because of this error:

> Rails :: Secrets :: MissingKeyError: Missing encryption key to decrypt
>   secrets with. Ask your team for your master key and put it in ENV
>   ["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]

Can someone help me?

Comment: check `secrets.yml` and run `rake secret` to generate new secret key

Comment: Add this and show me:
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/mateus/Documentos/Rails Projects/trabalho_embarcados/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mateus/Documentos/Rails Projects/trabalho_embarcados/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/home/mateus/Documentos/Rails Projects/trabalho_embarcados/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mateus/Documentos/Rails Projects/trabalho_embarcados/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/mateus/Documentos/Rails Projects/trabalho_embarcados/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See ...

Answer (score 8):

If you try with the 'previous' method of generating secret keys, with `rails secret` or `rake secret`, then you'll end up with another error: `ArgumentError: key must be 16 bytes`.

The easiest way to make this work with Heroku is:

`` heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/master.key` ``

or just take the first 32 characters (16 bytes) from `rails secret`

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: Hello, what if I use Digital Ocean and Capistrano?

Comment: @ValterEkholm you may need to ssh to your Digital Ocean servers and set  `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable there or do it with Capistrano https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit#users-working-directories-environment-variables-and-umask

Answer (score 5):

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`rake secret`
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to solve this problem.

1. create secrets.yml.key file which contains the key(encrypted).
2. heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`rake secret`.