# Can't decrypt config/credentials.yml.enc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am using Heroku with Rails 6 and Postgres. I am trying to use `heroku open` to start the app, but the build fails and this is shown in the logs:

```
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_9537ba0878cb8933c15686548eb3ccb5/config/application.rb:7)
       Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to /tmp/build_9537ba0878cb8933c15686548eb3ccb5/config/master.key or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'].
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

I have tried to run some of the commands mentioned in these two links, but none seem to work:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32947

[Ask your team for your master key and put it in ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"] on heroku deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298334/ask-your-team-for-your-master-key-and-put-it-in-envrails-master-key-on-herok)

I'm also wondering if these workflows are environment specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the rails master key as an environment variable to `heroku`.

1. Copy the master key in the `config/master.key` file in your computer
2. Add master key to `heroku` as environment variable

   ```
   heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=your-master-key
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem and don't use Heroku just copy credentials.yml.enc and master.key from the branch that works to the branch that has the problem.